# objective C OSX - Delegate- unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

The changeView_ShowContact method will make a view controller to show up just fine. But when I call the changeView_ShowContact from another class it wont work. Im getting an error in the log "unrecognized selector sent to instance."

```
@protocol callingActions_fromMainNavigation <NSObject>
    - (IBAction)changeView_ShowContact:(id)sender;
@end

**@interface Navigation_Main : NSViewController**
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <callingActions_fromMainNavigation> delegate;

**@implementation Navigation_Main** 
@synthesize delegate;

- (IBAction)changeView_ShowContact:(id)sender;
{
    NSLog(@"********************ShowContact");
    AddStuffViewController = [[pageContact alloc] initWithNibName:@"pageContact" bundle:nil];
    [AddStuffView addSubview:[AddStuffViewController view]]; //<This call here works ok.
}
```

.

```
@interface contacts : NSObject <callingActions_fromMainNavigation>

**@implementation contacts**
-(void)myMethodCall:(id)sender;
{
    Navigation_Main *NavMain = [[Navigation_Main alloc] initWithNibName:@"Navigation_Main.h" bundle:nil];
    [NavMain setDelegate:self];
    [self changeView_ShowContact:nil];
    //I need to call the (IBAction)changeView_ShowContact in the Main Navigation. This 
    //code is not working.
}
```

Comment: Underscores are rarely used in class names, and the `contacts` class should be capitalized and ideally have a unique prefix of 3 letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are having your `contacts` adopt the `callingActions_fromMainNavigation` protocol with out implementing `changeView_ShowContact:` in the `contacts` class.